# SciKit-Learn: Very Different Results with Cross Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm doing some basic machine learning using SciKit-Learn 0.18.1 and Python 2.7.  I'm trying to evaluate how good my model is by doing cross-validation.  When I do this:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, KFold

cv = KFold(n=5, random_state = 100)

clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=400, max_features = 0.5, verbose = 2, max_depth=30, min_samples_leaf=3)
score = cross_val_score(estimator = clf, X = X, y = y, cv = cv, n_jobs = -1, 
                        scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error")
avg_score = np.mean([np.sqrt(-x) for x in score])
std_dev = y.std()
print "avg_score: {}, std_dev: {}, avg_score/std_dev: {}".format(avg_score, std_dev, avg_score/std_dev)
```

I get a low `avg_score` (~9K).

What's troubling is that, despite specifying 5 folds, my `score` array has only 3 items in it.  In contrast, when I do this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
```

and run the same code (except for `n` becoming `n_splits`), I get a way worse RMSE (~24K).

Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cv = KFold(n=5, random_state = 100)
```

According to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold 
n is the total number of examples and n_folds, which defaults to 3, is the number of CV folds. It seems like you're only running CV with 3 folds and 5 examples, which is probably causing the discrepancy.
Maybe change `n` to `n_folds`

Comment: Note that I'm first doing `from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, KFold` so it should be `n`

Comment: In that case, isn't n the number of examples and n_folds the number of folds?

Comment: Also, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold makes me think sklearn.cross_validation.KFold is deprecated